# segmentation fault using char pointer (C)

Tags: c, pointers

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong in this block of code for a while now and still no luck. According to GDB, I'm receiving a SIGSEV, Segmentation Fault which means that I tried to access an invalid memory address.

Here I'm trying to find the length of the char pointer that is being passed

```
int getLength(char *start) {
 int count = 0;
 while(*start) {
   count++;
   start++;
 }
 return count;
}
```

Here is my full C file. I think it might be useful

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int len1 = getLength(argv[1]);
    int len2 = getLength(argv[2]);  

    if (argc != 3) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of items input.\n");
     return 1;
    }

    if (len1!=len2) {
     fprintf(stderr,"From and to are not the same size.\n");
     return 1;
    }
    return 0;   
 }

 int getLength(char *start) {
    int count = 0;
    while(*start) {
     count++;
     start++;
    }
   return count;
 }

 int duplicatesFrom(char *from) {
   int i;
   int j;

   int len = getLength(from); 

   for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
      if (from[i]==from[j] && i!=j) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us how you allocate and initialize `start`

Comment: ...and how you call `getLength`.

Comment: You must own the memory at start, up to and including the null terminator. Also, it would be nice to see const char* as the parameter type.

Comment: Just updated post guys. @EdS

Comment: You are checking argc after using getLength on argv.

Comment: I rollbacked the question since you edited it with suggestions made in the answer. Your edit was not correct as it invalidated the accepted answer, the question must show the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you don't give at least 3 arguments to your program, it will crash since you call `getLength` with the second and third argument as parameters at the beginning of `main()`.

I suggest you move the two first lines below the argument count check.

Then, as suggested by BathSheba, you shoud consider making the `char *` passed to `getLength()` `const` since `getLength()` doesn't modify it. It is a good practice and make the code more self-explanatory.

Also, do not forget the forward declaration of the functions you use in `main()` if their definition are below `main()`, unless you put the forward declaration in a header file (neither are present in your code snippet).

On last thing : in `getLength()`, you should check if the `char *` passed is valid by doing something like `if (start){...}`. Because if `start == NULL`, your program will crash since you will try to access a null pointer.

Following your edit : you can not separate an `if()` statement and the `else if()` logically following it. The `else if()` can be changed to `if()` here since in the case you enter the first `if()`, you quit the program (`return 1;`). And if you don't (if there is 3 arguments passed to the program), you can check safely if `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` have the same length.

Your main, slightly modified :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of items input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int len1 = getLength(argv[1]);
    int len2 = getLength(argv[2]);

    if (len1 != len2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s and %s are not the same size.\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", "Hello\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh shoot, I thought I moved that. Probably forgot or something...now I'm getting an else without a previous if error

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks for the explanation. Really appreciate it.